# curl / download in batch

Tags: linux, macos, curl

there is this scenario, where files exist in 100 folders in the following structure and convention.

> MYDOMAIN.com/2013/public/download/2/source2.zip
>
> MYDOMAIN.com/2013/public/download/3/source3.zip
>
> .
>
> .
>
> MYDOMAIN.com/2013/public/download/100/source100.zip

This script should ideally work, but it it's not downloading anything.

> curl
>   http://MYDOMAIN.com/2013/public/download/[1-100]/source[1-100].zip

Can someone please help me fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me (curl 7.34.0, Arch Linux 64 bit).
Maybe you should set output to files, like:

```
curl http://MYDOMAIN.com/2013/public/download/[1-100]/source[1-100].zip -o "#1_#2"
```

Comment: -o "#1_#2" these parameters helped.

internal error: invalid pattern type (0)
Warning: bad output glob!


Thanks!!